# Django Admin Tables Functionality

Tags: django, django-admin, datatables, mezzanine

Is there anyway to add the functionality of [Datatables](http://www.datatables.net/)
to the django admin interface. I'm using Django + Mezzanine and for my project we need the ability to sort  by every column, have pagination, search, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

The simplest implementation without server-side pagination would be overriding `change_list.html` for the model in order to:

- print the table in `{% block result_list %}`
- initialize datatable in `{% block extrahead %}`
- import css in `{% block extrastyle %}`